# Access Ribbon Addin in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I've been using an "Entrust" encryption tool that allows me to encrypt an internal email through Outlook.  Now I'm tasked with creating an automation using VSTO to create an encrypted email via C#.   Creating the email is not a problem, but I cannot find a way to access/discover the encrypt function in the addin.   I can see it in the ribbon of the email box, but can't find a way to access it.  I tried creating my own addin, and cant seem to access it either via a C# VSTO application....   Looking for suggestions for Office v2013 and above.  A screen shot of the Ribbon is below for reference:
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Entrust, but I see they have SDKs. Since you are already a customer you might have access to them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these buttons belong to a third-party add-in, not Outlook. In that case I'd suggest contacting the software vendor for any public API which can be used from other add-ins or applications.

Also you may consider using the [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) which allows clicking programmatically the required ribbon button.